# What is the 555 doing in this circuit?

Tags: 555, high-voltage

I'm trying to understand, from a functional standpoint, how the 555 timer plays a role in this circuit?

[image]

What I understand:

- Astable at f = 7.142kHz
- It's supply is the 150VDC.
- It's floating on R6.

The highside is turned on, the low side is PWM at f = 2kHz. Duty is changed as per the control loop.

To me, it looks like it is trying to push current to U10. But I'm a bit confused looking this one... Any info will help. Thanks.

Comment: Since you have a complete schematic with values and part numbers, then: **LTSpice is your friend**. It's free, and you'll learn a lot by simulating the circuit, too.

Comment: It's a charge pump with a voltage doubler that raises the V(B) voltage above +15HV for the high side FET driver.

Comment: Looks like a 7.142kHz clock....